# UnboundLocalError when running code, this makes no sense at all

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone help with this?
yesterday when I finished this code and tested all my possabilities, it worked. But today it dosn't work at all, it just produces an error.

my code:

```
def parseCSV(string):

    results = []
    current = ''
    quoting = False
    quoting = False


    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        currentletter = string[i]

        if currentletter == '"':
            if quoted == True:
                if quoting == True:
                    current = current + currentletter
                    quoting = False 
                else:
                    quoting = True

            else:
                quoted = True
                quoting = False

        else:

            shouldCheck  = False

            if quoted == True:

                if quoting == True:
                    quoted = False
                    quoting = False

                    shouldCheck = True

                else:
                    current = current + currentletter

            else:
                shouldCheck = True

            if shouldCheck == True:
                if currentletter == ',':
                    results.append(current)
                    current = ''

                else:
                    current = current +  currentletter

    results.append(current)
    return results


# Main
#Split CSV
Result = parseCSV('a,"b,c",d')
print(Result)
```

error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'quoted' referenced before assignment
```

Can anyone explain what an UnboundLocalError is? Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you ever actually set 'quoted' equal to something before you used an if statement? Maybe you set it to something on the console and forgot to include it in your main code.

Answer (score 0):

wrong code: mistake was that i set quoting twice when one of them was supposed to be quoted.

```
def parseCSV(string):

    results = []
    current = ''
    quoting = False
    quoting = False


    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        currentletter = string[i]

        if currentletter == '"':
            if quoted == True:
                if quoting == True:
                    current = current + currentletter
                    quoting = False 
                else:
                    quoting = True

            else:
                quoted = True
                quoting = False

        else:

            shouldCheck  = False

            if quoted == True:

                if quoting == True:
                    quoted = False
                    quoting = False

                    shouldCheck = True

                else:
                    current = current + currentletter

            else:
                shouldCheck = True

            if shouldCheck == True:
                if currentletter == ',':
                    results.append(current)
                    current = ''

                else:
                    current = current +  currentletter

    results.append(current)
    return results


# Main
#Split CSV
Result = parseCSV('a,"b,c",d')
print(Result)
```

Can someone close this? Thanks

Comment: You can delete your own question. You wrote it and there are no other answers, so you can use the delete button under your question to delete it.